# EF 6 Error with NoTracking when navigating back and forth using the Proxy's Navigation Properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, lazy-loading

In our EF 6 Code first application, we have issues with navigation properties in a non-tracking scenario.

The requirements are:

- Entity must not be attached to the context and retrieved via NoTracking
- Proxy Generation must be enabled and Lazy Loading working
- You have to navigate to another Entity via a Navigation Property and then back again to the origin entity

Error Message

> When an object is returned with a NoTracking merge option, Load can only be called when the EntityCollection or EntityReference does not contain objects.

In code it would look something like this (untested example, should demonstrate the essential parts):

```
public class A
{
  public virtual ICollection<B> NavigateToB { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
  public virtual A NavigateToA { get; set; }
}

public class AMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<A>
{
  public AMap() 
  {
    this.HasMany(a => a.NavigateToB)
         WithRequired(b => b.NavigateToA);
  }
}

public class BMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<B>
{
  public BMap() 
  {
    this.HasRequired(b => b.NavigateToA)
        .WithMany(a => a.NavigateToB);
  }
}

//Sample
var query= ARepository.GetQuery();
var a= query.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault();
var b = a.NavigateToB.FirstOrDefault();
var a2 = b.NavigateToA; //Here the error is thrown
```

The proxy objects do work just fine - I can use the navigatio properties multiple level's deep. The only problem appears when I navigate a navigation property back with above exception.
It's almost like the first time the navigation link has been used has stored the item in the collection, but not marked the reference as loaded.

Is there anything which can be done - potentially via reflection clearing the collection before lazy loading in case it has not been marked as loaded?

Comment: Can't reproduce - EF6.1.3, no exception, lazy loading works.

Comment: Hi @IvanStoev thanks for trying. Lazy loading does work for me too - it fails however when navigating back to the original. Using also EF 6.1.3.0225. If that works for you I think I need to provide a separated example.

Comment: I meant I've tried your sample exactly as it is, and it works, *including* the back navigation. May be you can try it yourself in a clean project. The only things I've added were `public int Id { get; set; }` to `A` and `B`.

Comment: thanks a lot @IvanStoev - my production code is different of course - but the core principle makes is the same. So if that works for you, I will now try and reproduce the issue indendent of the product code. Maybe that helps already finding the issue. Thanks